# What is difference between the events requestexception loadexception?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have read that `requestexception` is an event of `Ext.data.Connection`, while `loadexception` is an event of `Ext.data.HttpProxy`. I need some clarity as to whether there is any difference between the two, and I also want to know in what order are these triggered.

My understanding tells me that requestexception is called when there is an error in fetching data from server because of time-out or something else, while loadexception is called when data has been fetched, but Reader is not able to understand the data fetched, or there are no rows returned, or server returns `{success : false}`.

But in my code, whenever there is case of time-out, both the events are getting fired...so can't understand the need of one over the other. Please help...